# Elastic Beanstalk Django migrate issue

Tags: django, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying Django app to the AWS EB using CLI and noticed that EB doesn't see new migrations files for the first time. So, when I have new migrations I need to deploy twice. I looked at logs and indeed migrations were not found for the first time and found for the second time.
Here is my code for migrations:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "python ras-server/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Am I need to change commands order? Also, I think that issue could be with Jenkins as I deploy from Jenkins. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Jenkins: for some reason when I deployed using execute shell migrations where not found for the first time.
The solution is to use [Elastic Beanstalk Deployment plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin). Also, it takes less time to deploy with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Same Error for me. In my case. I forgot to include App name in the migration. Try including App name **exams**

```
01_migrate:
  command: "python manage.py makemigrations exams --noinput"
  command: "python manage.py migrate exams --noinput"
  leader_only: true
```